# How to create a script when wget failed: Connection refused to perform a restart

Tags: shell-script, scripting, wget

How to create a script when wget failed: Connection refused to perform a restart

**If it does not download the file, restart the server**

Connecting to 192.168.10.10 ... failed: Connection refused.

**When the file downloads, do nothing**

summary 100% [==================>] 3.28K --.- KB / s in 0s
2020-12-05 00:08:26 (138 MB / s) - ‘summary’ saved [3361/3361]

Thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why would you want to restart an entire web server instead of just the web service?

Comment: This is an application that has a web service, running under a port such as port 9090.
I need to make sure that the application's website is available, and if not, restart the application.

The application runs once in a while, but it is in a state that the website is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to restart the server when wget fails:

```bsh
wget -q -O /dev/null http://localhost:9090 || systemctl restart yourserver
```

This could then be added to a cron entry, for example.

Comment: Perfect, it works.
Thank You Very much